# My ajax is altering form action/URL thus makes me impossible to read the $tid from it

Tags: webforms, files

I am using WEBFORMS which have as the topic taxonomy terms saved as hidden fields.

Unfortunate, after attaching files using Upload button this terms are lost ('No category'), as ajax is altering the form #action URL from

`/tid` e.g. `/19`

```
/file/ajax/submitted/file4/form-gTwVpNbQRszArGEUS1OfuwA8WgSLJOlcWGOuS6r9D5A
```

I have multiple file forms

From where to read $tid?

Therefore my $tid fail to load from URL

```
      function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_') === 0) {
        $tid = arg(1);
                  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
                    if (!empty($term)) {
                        $category = i18n_taxonomy_term_name($term, $language->language);
                    } else {
                        $category = 'No category';
                    }
                    $form['submitted'][$category_fieldkey] = array(
                        '#type' => 'hidden',
                        '#value' => $category,
                    );

           // UP TO 10 FORM FIELDS
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                $form['submitted']['file' . $i] = array(
                    '#title' => t('File'),
                    '#type' => 'managed_file',
                    '#description' => t('Please upload a document or image.'),
                    '#default_value' => variable_get('file' . $i, ''),
                    '#weight' => 100,        

// ADD FORM SUBJECT
            $form['submitted']['subject'] = array(
                '#type' => 'item',
                '#title' => t('Subject'),
                '#markup' => '<div class="form-subject">' . $subject . '</div>',
                '#weight' => -100,
            );

                );
            }

    }
     return $form;    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you dpm your request_uri() or your current_path() after your the ajax query, don't you get the tid from the url ?

Comment: @Gregory Kapustin Unfortunatelly No: request_uri() is giving me this url:

/file/ajax/submitted/file4/form-tRe8TcTiu5n0C43Kp5M8yIbehkL9iprj6lj0dXt2tfg

Comment: Your file field is also in your form_alter ?

Comment: @Gregory Kapustin Yes of course

Comment: Actually ajax is altering my form's #action

Comment: If your file field is also in your form alter, you might send your tid to the callback, and re-take it after... What do you think ?

Comment: Sounds cool..but I don't get it :). How to I send the tid to ajax callback? I actually don't have an idea where the hack is the webform's ajax callback

Comment: You can use [that hack](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7#comment-16054) : `$form_state['triggering_element']['#name']` and put your tid in file field's name

Comment: Hi Gregory, sounds great. The blocker I have is I am using webform API and I really don't know the ajax callback for that. How can I find it?

Comment: Can you give us all your custom code ?

Comment: @Gregory I have updated the code...I don't know what else would be relevant. The Upload button is added by the webform module. My concern is as I have up to 10 file fields I will have all 10 filenames the same. –

Answer (score 0):

At the very end, you could use a variable_set on if(!empty(arg(1))) and retrieve it with variable_get on if(empty(arg(1))), but I'm sure there's a cleaner way.